# How to set default value to datetime variable. So that data type does not change to string

Tags: python, pandas

there is a variable type date in a method. and its default value is None. I m sending date type element but in that method, the variable type is changed to str by default

```
# these are imports
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
```

i am calling this method with:

```
df["date_col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_col"]).dt.date
end_date = pd.to_datetime("2021-07-19").date()
start_date = pd.to_datetime("2021-07-14").date()

df = subset_by_date(df,start_date,end_date)
```

This is method body:

```
def subset_by_date(df,start_date:date = None,end_date:date=None):
    if start_date is not None and end_date is not None:
        df = df.loc[(df["date_col"] <= end_date) & (df["date_col"] >= start_date)]
    return df
```

if you see start_date and end_date are date type. but this method is throwing error : TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'. And when I have print the data type then i have got

```
print(type(df["date_col"][0]), type(start_date), type(end_date))
```

getting this as output:

```
<class 'datetime.date'> <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
```

As far as I understood setting default as None is changing the data type. But I want to know how to set a default value for datetime variable so that the data type does not changed.

one approach is to take start_date and end_date as a string and change the data type to datetime in the method itself. But I want to know any other approach other than this.Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you _calling_ the function?

Comment: How are you comparing them?bcz the dtypes are different

Comment: @HenryEcker subset_by_date(df, pd.datetime(start_date).date(), pd.datetime(end_date).date())

Comment: @AnuragDabas if you see the method the data type for start and end date is set to date

Comment: You don't currently have enough information in your question. What imports are you using. How are `start_date` `end_date` definied. What are the dtypes of the dataframe. etc, etc,

Comment: @HenryEcker let me edit the question

Comment: Wait. `type(df["date_col"])` should _not_ be `<class 'datetime.date'>`. It should be `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` at some point there's been a wrong assignment.

Comment: @HenryEcker can you check now. that was a type while writing the question